# Алгоритм проверки на вхождение элемента в массив

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день.

Есть простейшая задача: существует огромнейший массив строк по 64 символа, периодически нужно проверять, присутствует ли в нем входная строка.
Осложняется задача тем, что хранить где-либо этот массив не представляется возможным. Но есть возможность один раз посчитать, скажем, какой-нибудь хеш этого массива или что-то эдакое. Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли создать какую-либо "свертку" этого массива, по которой можно проверить был ли какой-либо элемент в массиве, по которому посчитана эта "свертка". "Свертка" эта должна быть сильно меньше исходного массива. Данные в массиве рандомны, исходные данные восстанавливать не нужно, допускается любая погрешность <100%

Существует ли решения подобных задач?

Comment: CRC32 храните. Погрешность точно меньше 100% :-)

Comment: Всех благодарю за оперативность. Уже смотрю, гуглю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы посмотреть [фильтры Блума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0) - быстро, если показывает, что строки нет - то ее 100% нет, если есть - то можно оценить вероятность ложного срабатывания.

Смысл примерно такой - битовые хеш-значения просто суммируются операцией "или", а потом искомый хеш проверяется с использованием "и". Если все его единичные биты на месте - *возможно*, это значение имеется в наличии. При несовпадении - его точно нет.

Нужно только выбрать достаточную хэш-функцию :)

Вот еще один [источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112069/).